# how to write in stdout after to call a method (doing a system of notifications automatic (Iphone))

Tags: iphone, python, stdout, push-notification

I'm trying to do a system of notifications automatic (Iphone) using https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs. When you want to send a notification you call "apns.gateway_server.send_notification(key, payload)" and you have to enter the PEM pass phrase. Is there a way to enter this phrase through code?

Something like: call(apns.gateway_server.send_notification(key, payload), sys.stdout.write("my phars"))

I don't know how to do it

Comment: You might want to try asking in a more specific forum, like a mailing list about the library you're using.

Comment: I forget to combine the certificate and key, so that's why each time it asked me for the phrase. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
import apns

gate = apns.APNs('keyfile','certfile').gateway_server()
gate.send_notification(key,payload)
```

Is there a problem when you run this?