# How to pass user input automatically to a Python script?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write in stdout after to call a method (doing a system of notifications automatic (Iphone))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657900/how-to-write-in-stdout-after-to-call-a-method-doing-a-system-of-notifications-a)

I have the following script, that I want to execute automatically in a django app. The issue is that it keeps asking for user input.

I would like to know How to pass user input automatically? This is the script:

```
from apns import APNs, Payload

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='cert.pem', key_file='key.pem')

# Send a notification
token_hex = 'b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b87'
payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
my_pass_phrase = 'efisgbieafb3939bg93g238g4792gff9'
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

The issue happens at the following line:

```
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

The script asks: Enter PEM pass phrase: and waits for user input.

I would like to know how to pass the pass phrase automatically. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a library and probably don't have direct access to suppress the asking for user input, what you might have to do in the code that calls this script is use the `pexpect` module to watch for specific patterns in the output, and then send input appropriately:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect-u/2.5.1

Examples here: http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Might be something like:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('myAPNscript.py')
child.expect('Enter PEM pass phrase:.*')
child.sendline('FOO')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise, although is not working yet. Any ideas? I am planning to use this in a django function and not from a script file.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? You would have to call this as a script in order to use pexpect, since it will only be working with the stdout PIPE of the command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the requirement (it needs to be a script). I included the info and error on the question description.

Comment: You are mis-using pexpect. You cannot pass `spawn` a python function. It wants you to pass a string that will be executed in the shell. That means you have to put this into a script that you can call like "python script.py". You would pass that command string to pexpect and it will run it in another process.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try, although it will require passing my function variables / arguments to myAPNscript.py

Comment: Ya unfortunately it will require that. This would still be the easiest approach to allow you to hook into it, by making it a separate process with only stdout and stdin pipes to care about.